What does this equation for density mean?
What does this equation for density mean?
$$\rho = \lim_{\Delta V\to\varepsilon^3} \ \frac{\Delta m}{\Delta V}$$

This seems like a perfectly reasonable question, if someone has not been exposed to calculus and it's application to physics.

Where is this equation from? Were $\Delta m$, $\Delta V$, and $\epsilon$ defined? Is $\rho$ being defined at a point $x$? Did the source specify that "$\epsilon\rightarrow 0$? Related: "Density definition implies total mass integral". Also related: "Mass-density functions: how is there mass-density at points?" and "How do we define density (real one, not mathematical)?"?.

In the equation for density:
$$\rho = \lim_{\Delta V\to\varepsilon^3} \ \frac{\Delta m}{\Delta V}$$
$\rho$ is density.
$\Delta V$ represents a small change in volume.
$\Delta m$ represents a small change in mass, corresponding to the change in volume $\Delta V$.
The symbol $\varepsilon^3$ signifies the volume of an infinitesimally small region, and taking the limit as $\Delta V$ approaches $\varepsilon^3$ allows us to consider the density at a single point in space. This concept is often used in calculus and mathematical analysis to define density at a point.

Thank you so much. This helps but why is it the symbol E^3. And why would the similar equation for pressure be E^2?

$\varepsilon^3$ I think represents an incrementally small 1 dimension cubed, i.e. 1d to the power of 3 is volume (3d), or an incrementally small volume. Not zero volume, but near to zero volume.

I would have thought $\Delta V \rightarrow 0$ would be a more standard and less confusing notation.

The SI units for pressure are kg * m^-1 * s^-2. This is because pressure is a force (kg * m) divided by an area (m^2). To find the pressure at an infinitesimally small point, you'd take the limit as the area the force is divided over approaches 0, ie E^2.
